# can i give current to all components using the same VCC and GND pin connection from arduino NANO

Tags: arduino, connection, project, arduino-nano

I'm making a remote control using Arduino NANO, so to connect it can I give current to all the components(joystick, NRF24L01, buttons, etc)? and how?

Comment: It depends upon how much current they draw. Arduino has a limit of how much total current it can supply.

Comment: I'm stuck with something can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you really want to connect peripherals (joystick, NRF24L01, buttons, ...) with VCC pin. I guess the voltage of the VCC pin is higher than 3.3V since Arduino wouldn't work properly if it is under 5V. Furthermore, as far as I know, the NRF24L01 should be connected to 3.3V pin unless you are using voltage converter or the NRF module itself has on-board voltage converter.

There are three possible power pins on Arduino you can connect to peripherals; 3.3V pin, 5V pin, and VCC pin. 3.3V pin and 5V pin can output up to 200mA and 1A, respectively. Note that VCC is for power **input**, not an output pin, meaning its driving capability depends on the power source (battery, power supplier, USB, ...), not Arduino itself.

I recommend you to upload the schematic you are considering to create, even it is a crude one.

Comment: can we discuss it on some personal platform can I get your email id?

Comment: @StillWiZ Sorry. I refrain from discussing through other platform. You can refer to great guidelines or tutorials provided by module vendors such as Sparkfun, Adafruit, DFRobot, and so on. Or why don't you ask some helps in Arduino community?